# How do you cascade border color and style with css?

Tags: html, css

I want to set a border color and border style ( like solid or dotted ) in one place in my css file and apply borders to elements just by doing something like this:

```
body {
    border-color: #333;
    border-style: solid;
}

div.heading {
    border-right-width: 1px;
}
```

Can this be done?

Do common browsers support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {
    border: 0px solid #333;
}

div.heading {
    border-right-width: 5px;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div style="width:100px; height:100px;background-color:grey;" class="heading"></div>

    <br /><br /><br /><br />

    <div style="width:100px; height:100px;background-color:grey;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

i guess this is what you really needs

Comment: this didn't quite work for me.  i had to do this: `* div, * h1, * h2, * h3 { border: 0px solid blue }`. Are you sure `* {}` works?

Comment: yes it does, tried the same code at my end... use the above code and create an html file you can see it in action

Answer (score 1):

no you cant apply css to body and hope it will affect all elements inside.. you will have to use some css selectors read something about it [HERE](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

Comment: I have been applying CSS to the body element for years, and its children all inherit whatever can be inherited.

Comment: @Bolt: No, that is just insane for styles like border and it dont work:-) http://jsfiddle.net/8D65Z/

Answer (score 1):

you can write like this

**common style**

```
*{
border:0 solid #333;
}
```

OR

```
div.heading, body {
        border:0 solid #333;
    }
```

**override the common style**

```
div.heading {
    border-right-width: 2px;
}
```

Comment: The global border shouldn't be 1 pixel wide, otherwise every single element is going to show a border.

Answer (score -1):

Yes this can be done.
You could also set a default buy defining a standard border in body with no width:

```
body {
border-style: none;
border-color: #000000;
border-width: medium;
}

div.withborder {
  border-style: solid; 
}
```

This will set default border to 'medium, color #000000' but will turn off borders for all elements by default. When you set the border of any element to 'solid', it will automatically inherit the other options (color, width) you set.

EDIT: the following code was tested and worked:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
border-style: none;
border-color: #000000;
border-width: medium;
}

.withborder {
  border-style: solid; 
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p>No border.</p>
<p class="withborder">A solid border.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure it works? Try giving your first rule a different border color and see if the paragraphs inherit it.